# Instrumentation Tests with usage of Spoon setup error

Tags: android, testing, gradle, spoon

I am trying to run my tests with usage of Spoon.

According to setup guide I found there: https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin , I've set few simple changes to my project.

First: I've added dependency in my root build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        (...)
    }
    dependencies {
        (...)
        classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Second: in my app package build.gradle I've added:

```
apply plugin: 'spoon'
```

And dependency:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.1.9'
```

And specified that I want to use debug builds:

```
spoon {
    debug true
}
```

Third: I go to terminal, set directory to my project root and invoke

```
./gradlew spoon
```

I receive this output and error. What may be causing this?

```
2015-10-20 17:28:12 [SR.runTests] Executing instrumentation suite on 1 device(s).
2015-10-20 17:28:12 [SR.runTests] Application: com.azimo.sendmoney.debug1 from /Users/F1sherKK/Dev/Azimo-Android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
2015-10-20 17:28:12 [SR.runTests] Instrumentation: com.azimo.sendmoney.debug1.test from /Users/F1sherKK/Dev/Azimo-Android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk
2015-10-20 17:28:12 [SR.runTests] [1903cdc7] Starting execution.
2015-10-20 17:28:12 [SDR.run] InstrumentationInfo: [com.squareup.spoon.SpoonInstrumentationInfo@7baf516e[applicationPackage=com.azimo.sendmoney.debug1,instrumentationPackage=com.azimo.sendmoney.debug1.test,testRunnerClass=android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner]]
2015-10-20 17:28:12 [SDR.run] Got realDevice for [1903cdc7]
2015-10-20 17:28:12 [SDR.run] [1903cdc7] setDeviceDetails com.squareup.spoon.DeviceDetails@22444900[model=GT-I9505,manufacturer=samsung,version=5.0.1,apiLevel=21,language=en,region=GB,isEmulator=false,avdName=<null>]
2015-10-20 17:28:12 [SR.runTests] [1903cdc7] Execution done.
:app:spoonDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:spoonDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.installPackage(Ljava/lang/String;Z[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what caused error in my case. To delete:

```
com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.installPackage(Ljava/lang/String;Z[Ljava/lang/String;‌​)Ljava/lang/String
```

I had to change my gradle build tools. I was using before:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta2'
```

I had to change it to:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

To recreate the problem you can pull from gradle-plugin git example project. There is:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
```

used. And after you update it to 1.4.0 it gives same error as I have. I tested: 1.3.1 works, 1.4.0beta2-beta6 gives error so far.

Edit:
Error was fixed after update of runner and spoon client. Use:

```
  androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.2.1'
```

and

```
   classpath 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-runner:1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

this solves it for me:

```
classpath 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-runner:1.2.0'
classpath('com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.0.3') {
        exclude module: "guava"
}
```

some background:
https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin/issues/74

Comment: Hello, thanks for response. I saw this thread today already. Tried all combinations and also your code. My output doesn't change unfortunately no mather what I do:  

com.android.ddmlib.IDevice.installPackage(Ljava/lang/String;Z[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; 

is always there.

Comment: you added:  'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-runner:1.2.0' ? and did a clean?

Comment: I did add. I didn't perform clean so I will try it again. I did only gradle sync before. Question is, why do you exclude guava, are you adding it too? Like: classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0' somewhere?

Comment: Got output. After adding 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-runner:1.2.0' and performing clean, output doesn't change.